# Image Search inside another Image

Tags: image, image-processing, hash, phash

I want to find similar images for a given image file.

[image]

For example:

Images 1,2,4,5 are similar.

Images 4,5,6,7 are similar. 3 may be similar with those.

I have tested http://www.phash.org/demo/ . There are three algorithms it is used: Radial,DCT, Marr/Mexican.

DCT suggests 1-2 as similar. But it doesn't find 1-4 as similar.

Can you suggest different libs, algorithms especially to find 1-4 as similar?
As I said before my aim is to find (1,2,4,5) as similar and (4,5,6,7) as similar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you define "similar images" as images that contain the same objects.

Therefore,when comparing two images, you can apply segmentation to get the objects from one  image and then apply template matching to check if that object is in the second image. Then, you can switch the roles of the images and apply the same procedure again.